# Initialize std::array by parameter pack from arbitrary index

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

Initializing an `std::array` by variadic template arguments, starting from a given index can be done the following way:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
   template <typename ... Ts>
   A(size_t i, Ts ... vals)
   {
      constexpr size_t P = sizeof...(vals);
      std::array<T, P> temp{ vals... };

      for (size_t j = 0; j < P; ++j)
      {
         arr[i + j] = temp[j];
      }
   }

   std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

But is it possible to achieve the same without converting the parameter pack to a temporary tuple or another std::array?

Comment: @Yakk: The whole point of using C++ these days is performance. Creating temporary containers is antithetical to that. It takes up needless space and causes the invocation of needless constructors, possibly allocating lots of resources depending on what `T` is. I see no need why he should have to justify why he doesn't want to convert the parameter pack to some kind of object.

Comment: It seems to me Monday morning is kinda hard for people after Easter. The question is crystal clear, but I see two respectful members of SO bomarding OP with irrelevant statements instead of answering the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Those are all great reasons to put in.  But a `std::tie` is a container of references whose existence and size can (in theory) be elided.  And it is a tuple.

Comment: SergeyA is totally right. And actually this is the attitude I really don't like on stackoverflow sometimes. Instead of doing any positive or building comments, just irrelevant questions, insulting, etc. Please take some time and look at the assembly of a tuple utilizing code generated with -O1 and I need no more explanations.

Comment: @plasmacel : If you don't know the answer to your own question (and why ask if you do?) then you cannot possibly know what is and is not relevant.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not 100% familiar with the new possibilities of C++14 and the upcoming C++17 voted features. This is why I'm curious about possible better solutions. It doesn't mean that I can't distinguish between the relevance of the comments. And yours sir, about product types is just ridiculous. Of course tuples are extremely useful, but they are not a primer for initialization. It is true that currently, lacking a better language feature, tuples are the only solution for many parameter pack handling problem. But it doesn't mean that you shouldn't avoid them if it is possible.

Comment: @plasmacel : "*And yours sir, about product types is just ridiculous. Of course tuples are extremely useful, but they are not a primer for initialization.*" You didn't say that; I was replying to what you _did_ say. "Yeah I'm somewhat allergic to tuples, don't like them." is patently ridiculous.

Comment: At this point, probably better if all of us rethink the way we're leading the discussion. :) Regardless of nit picking, OP point is at this point clear enough. On to possible answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `std::index_sequence` and delegating constructor:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
   template <typename ... Ts>
   A(size_t i, Ts&& ... vals)
   :
       A(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, i, std::forward<Ts>(vals)...)
   {}

   template <std::size_t...Is, typename ... Ts>
   A(std::index_sequence<Is...>, size_t i, Ts&& ... vals)
   {
      int dummy[] = {0, ((arr[i + Is] = vals), void(), 0)...};
      static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
   }

   std::array<T, N> arr;
};
```

Or with Folding expression of C++17,

```
   template <std::size_t...Is, typename ... Ts>
   A(std::index_sequence<Is...>, size_t i, Ts&& ... vals)
   {
      (static_cast<void>(arr[i + Is] = vals), ...);
   }
```

Comment: @SergeyA In the comments OP specified he wants to avoid runtime costs.

Comment: @Yakk: with expression fold of c++1z, the dummy array may be removed: `((arr[i + Is] = vals), ...)`.

Comment: @Yakk Actually I think in this case the construction of the array == nop.

Comment: @YamMarcovic : That depends entirely on whether or not `T` is trivially default-constructible.

Comment: @ildjarn Right, thanks. My own previous example of `int` jumped back at me.

Comment: @ildjarn and that constructing then assigning is the same as just constructing.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not that array -- the `std::array` gets constructed, then populated with `[]=`.  Ick!

Answer (score 2):

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

template<class T, std::size_t=0, class...Args>
T make(Args&&...args){ return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

template <class T, size_t N>
struct A {
  template <std::size_t I, class...Ts>
  A(index_t<I>, Ts&&... vals):
    A(std::make_index_sequence<I>{}, std::forward<Ts>(vals)...)
  {}
  template <std::size_t...Is, class...Ts>
  A(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&...vals):
    arr{{ make<T,Is>()..., std::forward<Ts>(vals)... }}
  {}
  // ...
};
```

this requires a compile-time known offset, but avoids creating a default-constructed array then assigning to it.  It however also involves creating a pile of `T`s and moving them into the array.  Ick!

Backing up a second, we know that the array is a standard layout block of `T`s.  Let's cheat.

```
// stores the raw buffer for the array, and constructs it with
// some care:
template<class T>
using storage = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)>;
template<class T, size_t N>
struct A_storage {
  storage<std::array<T, N>> raw_arr;
  std::array<T,N>& arr() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<std::array<T, N>*>(&raw_arr);
  }
  std::array<T,N> const& arr() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<std::array<T, N> const*>(&raw_arr);
  }

  template<class...Ts>
  static void make_arr(storage<std::array<T, N>>& retval, std::size_t offset, Ts&&...ts) {
    auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&retval);
    try {
      std::size_t ctor_count = 0;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < offset; ++i) {
        ++ctor_count;
        ::new((void*)(ptr+i)) T();
      }
      ::new((void*)(ptr +offset)) std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)>{{
        (++ctor_count, void(), std::forward<Ts>(ts))...
      }};
      for (size_t i = offset+sizeof...(Ts); i < N; ++i) {
        ++ctor_count;
        ::new((void*)(ptr+i)) T();
      }
    } catch(...) {
      // ctor_count is the count of constructors *attempted*
      // so ptr[ctor_count-2] is the last one we *succeeded at*
      // destroy everything we successfully constructed.
      // ctor_count has to be at least 1, as we cannot throw before
      // incrementing.  Let us peel it off.
      --ctor_count;
      // iterate backwards from ctor_count-1 down to 0, so we destroy
      // in reverse order of constructing:
      for (size_t i = 1; i <= ctor_count; ++i) {
        ptr[ctor_count-i].~T();
      }
      throw;
      // I use attempted, because the initializer list syntax of array
      // construction doesn't let me increment after I provide the value
      // for the place I'm constructing.  I can, however, increment before.

    }
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  A_storage(std::size_t offset, Ts&&...ts)
  {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts)<=N, "too much data!");
    ASSERT(offset+sizeof...(Ts)<=N);
    make_arr(raw_arr, offset, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
  // only runs if the ctor above completes, which means
  // everything was constructed:
  ~A_storage() {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
      arr()[N-i].~T();
    }
  }
};
template<std::size_t N, class T>
struct A:A_storage {
  template<class...Ts>
  A(std::size_t offset, Ts&&...ts):
    A_storage(offset, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
  {}
};
```

Everything is constructed in-place.  No need for `T(T&&)` support!  (unless that is how you pass in the parameters to the array, but that is your problem not mine)

I tried to make destruction work in an exception-heavy environment.  I may have gotten it wrong.

The only temporary variable (the return value of `make_arr`) should be elided by NRVO.  On the other hand, a compiler might be a slacker and not elide into class member constructors.  Bad compiler.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't the value-initialized `T`s in the first version qualify for elision?

Comment: ...[yep](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f164c79e853b197). So the only actual problem is requiring `T` to be move constructible,  but that'll be solved by guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: @T.C. I think the `,` part ruins that?  Maybe not?  I  guess I could write `template<size_t I, class T, class...Args> T make(Args&&...args){ return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`, then replace `(Is, void(), T())...` with `make<Is, T>()...`.  Which gets rid of `,` operator abuse, a plus.  Replaced.  v1 also requires a compile-time known offset, which the OP doesn't have in the code, so v2 still is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Although it involves C++17 fold expressions, the simplest possible solution inspired by the comment of Jarod42 is:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
   template <typename ... Ts>
   A(Ts ... vals)
   {
     size_t i = 1; // starting index, can be an argument
     ((arr[i++] = vals) , ...);
   }

   std::array<T, N> arr;
};

int main()
{
   A<int, 4> a(1, 2, 3);

   return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with **Clang 3.6** or above with optimization level `-O1` and `-std=c++1z` flag the generated assembly is:

```
A<int, 4ul>::A<int, int, int>(int, int, int):             # @A<int, 4ul>::A<int, int, int>(int, int, int)
pushq   %rbp
pushq   %r15
pushq   %r14
pushq   %rbx
pushq   %rax
movl    %ecx, %r14d
movl    %edx, %r15d
movl    %esi, %ebx
movq    %rdi, %rbp
movl    $1, %esi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %ebx, (%rax)
movl    $2, %esi
movq    %rbp, %rdi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %r15d, (%rax)
movl    $3, %esi
movq    %rbp, %rdi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %r14d, (%rax)
addq    $8, %rsp
popq    %rbx
popq    %r14
popq    %r15
popq    %rbp
retq
```

Which is equivalent to the test case

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct B
{
   B(T x, T y, T z)
   {
     arr[1] = x;
     arr[2] = y;
     arr[3] = z;
   }

   std::array<T, N> arr;
};

int main()
{
   B<int, 4> b(1, 2, 3);

   return 0;
}
```

with generated assembly

```
B<int, 4ul>::B(int, int, int):                     # @B<int, 4ul>::B(int, int, int)
pushq   %rbp
pushq   %r15
pushq   %r14
pushq   %rbx
pushq   %rax
movl    %ecx, %r14d
movl    %edx, %r15d
movl    %esi, %ebx
movq    %rdi, %rbp
movl    $1, %esi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %ebx, (%rax)
movl    $2, %esi
movq    %rbp, %rdi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %r15d, (%rax)
movl    $3, %esi
movq    %rbp, %rdi
callq   std::array<int, 4ul>::operator[](unsigned long)
movl    %r14d, (%rax)
addq    $8, %rsp
popq    %rbx
popq    %r14
popq    %r15
popq    %rbp
retq
```

It's worth to note that the generated assembly of the two case is equivalent.